# Hyphenation of "trial and error"

Tags: hyphens

> Students learn by **trial and error**.

> Students learn by **trial-and-error**.

Should "trial and error" be hyphenated or not in the above sentence? What is the rule here? I have seen both usages.

Comment: I would only use hyphens when treating the phrase as an adjective - 'a trial-and-error method'.

Comment: @KateBunting - many would say further that we only employ hyphens if that compound adjective is used before a noun, e.g. _We found the solution by a trial-and-error method._

Comment: No. It would only be an adjective if you said 'by trial-and-error methods'.

Answer (score 1):

1. You use "trial-and-error" when it functions as an adjective: a trial-and-error method
2. In other cases you use "trial and error": by trial and error.

Comment: I think you mean **trial** and error.

Comment: If you spot a spelling mistake, edit to fix the mistake.  That's better than editing to say that there is a mistake.